# Check if data attribute of button is same as post class

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a post filter by adding a hidden-class to element that don't have a specific category. I have multiple buttons with a 'data-thema'-attribute, I want to check the attribute value of the clicked button and compare it to the classes of the post elements. When the post has no class that equals the data-thema value, I want to add a hidden-class to that element.

Now when a button is clicked, all posts get the class hidden. This is what I want, but it needs to check if there are any posts with the particular class and then remove the hidden-class again.

**This is what I have so far:**

**jQuery**

```
$('.intro .themaWrapper span').on('click', function() {
            var clickedTheme = $(this).attr('data-thema');

            $('.posts .post').each(function() {
                // $(this).addClass('hidden');

                if ($(this).hasClass(clickedTheme)) {
                    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $('.posts .post').addClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        });
```

**PHP**

```
foreach( $themas as $category ) {
            if( $category->parent == 0 ) {
                echo '<span class="btn blue" data-thema="'. esc_attr( $category->slug ) .'">';
                    echo $category->name;
                echo '</span>';
            }
        }

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $f = get_fields();

        $classes = '';
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'thema');

        foreach($terms as $t) {
            $classes .= $t->slug . ' ';
        }

        echo "<div class='post ". $classes ."'>";
            echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Just HTML output would be better.

Comment: _“Now when a button is clicked, all posts get the class hidden.”_ - not surprising, after all you wrote code that does exactly that: `$('.posts .post').addClass('hidden');` – no limitation to any _specific_ post here, just all of them. You managed to only _remove_ the hidden class from one specific post in the `if` branch - so why aren’t you doing the exact same thing when it comes to _adding_ it to this specific post, in the `else` branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can resume the whole logic to a single chained expression:

```js
$('span').on('click', function() {
    $('.posts .post')
        // Add the hidden class to all the posts
        .addClass('hidden')
        .removeClass('red')
         // Filter those with the same thema
        .filter('.' + $(this).data('thema'))
        // Remove the hidden class for the filter results
        .removeClass('hidden')
        .addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.posts {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-thema="thema-1">Thema 1</span>
<span data-thema="thema-2">Thema 2</span>
<span data-thema="thema-3">Thema 3</span>

<div class="posts">
  <div class="post thema-1">Thema 1 div</div>
  <div class="post thema-3">Thema 3 div</div>
  <div class="post thema-2">Thema 2 div</div>
  <div class="post thema-2 thema-1">Thema 1 and Thema 2 div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Some posts have multiple thema attribute values, could this be a problem?

Comment: How `$t->slug` looks like?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I was looking at the wrong attribute instead of looking on the `.post` classes

Comment: Still not working, I also added the thema-attrbute to the posts and tried it that was but also doesn't work.
An example of a slug is 'thema-1'

Comment: Just inspect the elements and make sure that `data-thema` from the spans also exists as classes in `.posts .post` elements. It should work, as I don't see any reason for it to not work

Comment: I just added an working example. Make sure that all the paths you added are the right ones

Comment: Looks like it interfered with some other code I'm using to fade in the posts. It's what I needed, thanks! Is it possible to add another class when the hidden-class is removed? I tried it myself but the hidden-class doesn't get removed now.